# When do we have $X^p = I$, where $X$ has entries from a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Say I only consider $2\times 2$ matrix $X$. $X$ has entries from a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$. When do we have $X^p = I$?

I looked into $\mathbb{Z_2}$ and found the following (excluding $I$ itself)

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix},
$$

What about $\mathbb{F}_p$ in general? I know that $x^p - 1 = (x-1)^p$ but is there a way to relate that to matrix?

**updated**: forgot to mention, but I would also like to *count* the number of such $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: If $X$ is diagonalisable, then $X=S^{-1} D S$ and $X^p=S^{-1} D^p S=S^{-1} D S=X$ as $\alpha^p=\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p$, so $X$ has to be the identity... For the general case you might want to use the Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an algebraic extension $E$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$ where the characteristic equation of $A$ has roots.

Since $A$ is $2 \times 2$, then $E$ is an extension of $ \mathbb{F}_p$ of degree $1$ or $2$, therefore has $p$ or $p^2$ elements.

Now, if $A$ would be diagonalisable over $E$, then $\lambda_{1,2}^{p^2-1}=1$ which means that $A^{p^2-1}=I$. But then $A^p=I$ implies that $A=I$.

Therefore, the only diagonalisable matrix which has this property is $A=I$.

Next, let us look at the non-diagonalisable possibilities.

We must have $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$, which means that for $p \neq 2$ we have 
$$\lambda_1=\lambda_2=2^{-1}\tr(A) \in \mathbb{F}_p$$

Then $A^p=I \Rightarrow \lambda^p=1 \Rightarrow \lambda =1$.

This shows that the only eigenvalues of $A$ must be $1$ and $1$.

Conversely, any matrix which has $1,1$ as eigenvalues satisfies 
$$(A-I)^2=0$$
and therefore
$$(A-I)^{p}=0 \Rightarrow A^p=I$$

So the problem boils down to find for $p \neq 2$ all the $2 \times 2$ matrices with eigenvalues $1$ and $1$.

This can be found either by checking how many $2 \times 2$ matrices have Jordan form $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}$ or by solving the system
$$a+d=2 \\
ad-bc=1$$

Comment: But how are we gonna _count_? From $a+d=2$, we have $p$ possibilities for combinations of $(a,b)$, but how do we decide $b$ and $c$?

Comment: @Misakov $$bc=ad-1=a(2-a)-1$$ Now, split the problem in two cases: 1) if $a(2-a)-1=0$, meaning if $a=1$ then, $bc=0$ which is easy to solve. 2) If $a(2-a)-1\neq 0$, then $c\neq 0$ and $b=c^{-1}a(2-a)-1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $X^p=I$, then all eigenvalues of $X$ are necessarily $p$-th roots of unity. But, since, as you have stated, $x^p-1=(x-1)^p$, in characteristic $p$, the only $p$-th root of unity is $1$, so the only eigenvalue is $1$, and the characteristic polynomial of $X$ is $(\lambda-1)^2$.

Since the characteristic polynomial decomposes into linear terms over ${\bf F}_p$, you can put $X$ into Jordan normal form, which (for $2\times 2$ matrices) will be either the identity or $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}$ (these are the only $2\times 2$ Jordan normal forms of matrices with eigenvalues equal to $1$). You can easily check that $I^p=A^p=I$, so these are the only ones up to conjugation, so all such $X$ are either $I$ or $PAP^{-1}$ for some $P\in \operatorname{GL}_2({\bf F}_p)$.

This can be generalised into larger dimensions: for the same reasons, if $X$ is $n\times n$, the characteristic polynomial will be $(\lambda-1)^n$. It is easy to check that the Jordan blocks in the normal form will be of size up to $p\times p$ (otherwise the off-diagonal terms will not vanish when raised to $p$-th power), and any such matrix will satisfy your equation.

Comment: I have only studied matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$... Where can I find resource on matrices over general field? For example, it is not immediately clear to me that we can carry over theorems and objects (eigenvalues, Jordan form) to general field...

Comment: @Misakov: I've been told that Kostrikin and Manin's "Linear algebra and geometry" is a very good textbook on linear algebra. They start with the very basics, so it should be possible to follow with minimal prerequisites. The caveat is that I haven't really read it myself, and I've simply been taught linear algebra over arbitrary fields as an undergraduate. Most of the elementary facts are really the same over arbitrary fields, except maybe that you may have no notion of positive definiteness of a bilinear form (so no inner products and, in general, no natural norms or metrics).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, $X^p=\mathrm{Id} \iff (X-\mathrm{Id})^p=0$. So find solutions $Y$ to $Y^p=0$.

Now, the chain of subspaces $V,YV,Y^2V,\cdots$ must eventually be $0$, and must decrease in dimension at every step (else it would stabilizer before $0$), so either the dimensions go $2,1,0$ or they go $2,0$. The latter case occurs when $Y=0$, so suppose we're in the first case. The image will be generated by some  column vector $(a,b)^T$. Then the columns of $Y$ are multiples of $(a,b)^T$, so for some scalars $u,v$ we have

$$ Y=\begin{pmatrix} ua & va \\ ub & vb \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u & v \end{pmatrix}. $$

Every $2\times 2$ singular matrix has this form, since determinant zeros implies the columns are linearly dependent, implies the columns are scalar multiples of each other. The condition $Y(a,b)^T=0$ is equivalent to $(a,b)\cdot(u,v)=0$, which is equivalent to $Y$ have trace equal to $0$.

This yields the following characterization: the $Y$ are precisely the $2\times 2$ matrices with both determinant and trace equal to zero.

Any two solutions $(u,v)$ to $au+bv=0$ will be related by a constant multiple (exercise), so we can say $(u,v)=c(-b,a)$ for some nonzero scalar $c$. This gives

$$Y=\begin{pmatrix} -abc & a^2c \\ -b^2c & abc\end{pmatrix}.$$

This parametrizes all possible $Y$, with some redundancy: one may scale $(a,b)$ by $r$ and $c$ by $r^{-2}$ without changing the value of $Y$. This identifies the set of all $Y$ with

$$ \big((\mathbb{F}_q^2\setminus0)\times\mathbb{F}_q\big)/\mathbb{F}_q^\times.$$

As $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ acts regularly on $\mathbb{F}_q^2\setminus 0$, it does so on $(\mathbb{F}_q^2\setminus0)\times\mathbb{F}_q$ too, so the number of solutions is

$$ \frac{(q^2-1)q}{q-1}=q(q+1). $$